# How to use ForEach on a NSSet generated by CoreData in SwiftUI

Tags: foreach, swiftui, nsset

I generated a CoreData model with some 1-to-many relationships. Now I want to use a ForEach on this relationship which is a `NSSet`, then I'm getting the following error:

```
Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'NSSet' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'
```

My code looks like this:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var sample: Sample

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(sample.stepps!, id: \.self) { step in
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure you want `ForEach` instead of `forEach`?

Comment: forEach does not work in SwiftUI

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is possible approach

```
ForEach(Array(sample.stepps! as Set), id: \.self) { step in
    // step is NSObject type, so you'll need it cast to your model
}
```

Comment: ...and if you have a slider inside you want to access like with a Slider(step.percentage) ? ...

Comment: but this solution does not work in the cases of a Set that will change

Comment: solution not working

Answer (score 2):

```swift
if let steps = sample.steps?.allObjects as? [Step] {
  ForEach(steps) {step in
    Text("\(step.title ?? "step")")
  }
}
```

Comment: This is worked very well, thank you a lot